# Does Chronicle Map have any concept of expiration

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Does Chronicle Map have any concept (or pluggable ability) to provide automatic entry expiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and I’m sorry we don’t have any plans to add this functionality in the near future.

Comment: Thanks. So how are such expiration problems typically handled within Chronicle - via a separate thread/process periodically scanning the map coupled with an expiration validation on the get() ?